# A function that works just in the beginning if the code

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, mqtt

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    var iotdata = new AWS.IotData({
        endpoint: 'endpoint'
    });
    exports.handler = function (event, context) {
        var params = {
        topic: 'topic',
        payload: 'payload',
        qos: 0
        };
        try {
            console.log("event.session.application.applicationId=" + event.session.application.applicationId);
            if (event.session.new) {
               console.log("NEW SESSION");
            }
            switch (event.request.type){ 
                case "LaunchRequest": 
                console.log(`LAUNCH REQUEST`);
                iotdata.publish(params, function(err, data){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log("!!!!!!!!");
                            context.succeed(
                                generateResponse(
                                    buildSpeechletResponse("Text1", true),
                                    {}
                            ));
                    }   
                });
                break;

            case "IntentRequest":
               console.log(`INTENT REQUEST`);
                if (event.request.intent.name==="Intent"){
                var number2 = event.request.intent.slots.Number.value;
                NumberS = NumberSwitch(number2);
                payLoad = 'payload';
                params={
                    topic: 'topic',
                    payload: payLoad,
                    qos: 0
                };
                iotdata.publish(params, function(err, data){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log("success");
                            context.succeed(
                                generateResponse(
                                    buildSpeechletResponse("Text2", true),
                                    {}
                            ));
                    }   
                });
            }else{throw "Invalid intent";}  
            break;

            case "SessionEndedRequest":
            console.log(`SESSION ENDED REQUEST`);
            break;

            default:
            context.fail(`INVALID REQUEST TYPE: ${event.request.type}`);
        }

    } catch (e) {
        context.fail("Exception: " + e);
    }
};
```

the execution result of starting the session is

> "version": "1.0",   "sessionAttributes": {},   "response": {
>       "outputSpeech": {
>         "type": "PlainText",
>         "text": "Text1"
>
> ```
> "shouldEndSession": true
> ```

but when i write the intent name on json file
the execution result is

> "errorMessage": "Exception: Invalid intent"

My Question is why the iot.publish function works just in launch request
and does not work in the intent request????

is there are any explanation??

Comment: `iot.publish()` does not seem to be called, it is `event.request.intent.name==="Intent"` that evaluates to `false`

Comment: it's called because the intent name is not Intent but i put it here because i don't want to reveal the Intent name